# Numbers of words allowing repetition

Tags: permutations

10 different letters of an alphabet are given. words with 5 letters are formed from these given letters.I have to determine the number of words which have at least one letter repeated.

Answer is - 69760

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Find out the total number of possible words (without any constraint). Then calculate the number of words in which no letter are repeated. Subtract the result obtained in 2nd case from 1st to get the answer.